# Unable to do a correct match

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hey guys I am working on a project in which,  I need to store device names in the file and then I am trying to find that name using `cat file | grep device`
and if that name exists i am trying to print the yes else no.I did this via the following code but I am unable to achieve the expected result, please point what's wrong.

```
echo "Please enter the name of your device"
read device
$(cat database | grep $device) = found
if ('$found' = '$device');then
        echo "yes"
else
        echo "Nope"
fi
```

Comment: Your sample bears only a passing resemblance to valid `bash` code; where are you learning `bash`?

Comment: @chepner myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the syntax wrong, try this instead:

```
echo "Please enter the name of your device"
read device
if grep -q "$device" database; then
        echo "yes"
else
        echo "Nope"
fi
```

You should find [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) useful when analyzing issues with your shell scripts.